# Keras TimeDistributed - are weights shared?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

From keras [docs](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/): You can then use `TimeDistributed` to apply a `Dense` layer to each of the 10 timesteps, independently:

```
# as the first layer in a model
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(8), input_shape=(10, 16)))
# now model.output_shape == (None, 10, 8)

# subsequent layers: no need for input_shape
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(32)))
# now model.output_shape == (None, 10, 32)
```

I cannot find it anywhere, Are the weights of the `Dense` layers shared across the time axis?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they are shared - exactly the same `Dense` is applied to each `timestep`. Moreover - in `Keras 2.0` the behaviour like `TimeDistributed` is now default for a `Dense` layer applied to input which has more than 2D (including `batch_dimension`).

Comment: Thank you, some reference might be better, but as I thought they were shared for like 90% and you seem you know what you're talking about, I believe you :) Nice new feature with 2D inputs, by the way.

Comment: Yes - I like the way Francois is developing `Keras` :)